# regex for allowing alphanumeric, special characters and not ending with @ or _ or

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am new to regex , I created below regex which allows alpha numeric and 3 special characters @._ but string should not end with @ or . or *

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._@]*[^_][^.][^@]$
```

it validates abc@ but fails for abc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern allows at least 3 characters, where the last 3 are negated character classes matching any char other than the listed.

The pattern `^[a-zA-Z0-9._@]*[^_][^.][^@]$` will [match 3 newlines](https://regex101.com/r/T6FqvR/1), and adding all the chars to a single character class `^[a-zA-Z0-9._@]*[^@._]$` will also [match a single newline](https://regex101.com/r/oro5Zw/1) only.

---

If you want to allow all 3 "special" characters and match at least 3 characters in total you can repeat the character class 2 or more times using `{2,}` and match a single char at the end without the special characters.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._@]{2,}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ewef0G/1)

Matching as least a single char (and not end with `.` `_` `@`)

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._@]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ig2MiS/1)

Comment: @ahsaankhan Note that `[^@._]` matches any char except what is listed. It can also match a newline char or any other char.

Comment: yeah using [^@._] allows abc*

Answer (score 1):

if you include all the characters in the one character set, that'll work.

`^[a-zA-Z0-9._@]*[^@._]$`

[image]

Screenshot shows how different text examples would work (try it out on http://regexr.com)

Answer (score 1):

Leading ^ is the start of the paragraph
Trailing $ is the end of the paragraph
. is the everything {2,} means the more than 2 letters
[^@_] means one letter Not @ or _

```
^.{2,}[^@_]$
```

[click here the answer](https://regex101.com/r/XcGItw/1)